# how to set a background on SurfaceView

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, android-canvas, surfaceview

this is the code i've tried so far..

```
package com.gtxradeon.brands;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;



public class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private CanvasThread canvasthread;
    public Paint paint;
    private Bitmap scaled;

    public Panel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        canvasthread = new CanvasThread(getHolder(), this);
        setFocusable(true);
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    public Panel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        setFocusable(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        //paint.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
        // canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
//      canvas.drawCircle(500f, 500f, 30, paint);

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.mapmarker);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp , 250f, 250f, null);   

    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.grocery);
//      float scale = (float) background.getHeight() / (float) getHeight();
//        int newWidth = Math.round(background.getWidth() / scale);
//        int newHeight = Math.round(background.getHeight() / scale);
//        scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, newWidth, newHeight, true);
        canvasthread = new CanvasThread(getHolder(), this);
        canvasthread.setRunning(true);
        canvasthread.start();

    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean retry = true;
        canvasthread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                canvasthread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // we will try it again and again...
            }
        }

    }

}
```

this is the xml file

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <!-- <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/grocery" /> -->

        <com.gtxradeon.brands.Panel
            android:id="@+id/SurfaceView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

i have tried the image view but it will not appear as a background because i think the surfaceview is on top of it.

i also tried setting the image as background like `android:background="@drawable/bg"`
but still doesn't display..

i have tried the solution from this thread [Setting image background in SurfaceView, getting black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089784/setting-image-background-in-surfaceview-getting-black-screen)
but still didn't helped me..

the only thing that is appearing is the maker i've displayed in the onDraw() method.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in onDraw(). But you should create this bitmap from factory earlier. Don't do this in onDraw().
There are some tricks to setup SurfaceView to make it [on Top of all views behind](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderMediaOverlay%28boolean%29). But you should understand requirements and choose more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

One can also set at the holder with `setFormat`, like what I did for a transparent surface view:

```
SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
holder.addCallback(this);
holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.OPAQUE);

// set the compass background as transparent
// holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to do a little hack-around to make any background work in SurfaceView, like this:

override the `setBackground` and `setBackgroundDrawable` methods

```
   Drawable background

   @Override
   public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background) {
      this.background = background;
   }

   @Override
   public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
      this.background = background;
   }
```

don't forget to call `setBounds` on the drawable

```
   @Override
   protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
      super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
      matrix = null;
      if (background != null)
         background.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
   }
```

then on the code you're locking, drawing, unlocking and posting the canvas you add the background

```
   Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
   if (background != null)
      background.draw(c);

   // do your stuff here

   holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

works for both XML and Java backgrounds.