# Surface refuses to display canvas.draw.. images?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I'm trying to add a `SurfaceView` to the background of my main activity to draw some funky images that'll wander about. (mainly used for a screensaver as our screens are on all the time). I've set it all out and setup the drawing thread and it run really well... But, the SurfaceView refuses to draw anything at all?!

As per [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089784/setting-image-background-in-surfaceview-getting-black-screen) I've set `.setWillNotDraw(false);` but still no change!

I then thought maybe it's the image I was using, so got a completely random one from the app and tried with that, but still nothing.. So then I tried just drawing a 32x32 yellow rectangle...Nothing :(

Any help is very much appreciated, as I'm clearly missing something.

LogCat states that:

```
11-27 16:20:26.854    8801-8869/com.goosesys.gaggle I/FLOAT﹕ Drawing f=176/194
11-27 16:20:26.854    8801-8869/com.goosesys.gaggle I/FLOAT﹕ Drawing f=342/759
etc ... etc ...
```

Here's some code:

```
    protected void drawFloaters(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK, Mode.MULTIPLY);
        for(Floater f : mIcons) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(f.getImage(), f.getX(), f.getY(), null);
            canvas.drawRect(f.getX(), f.getY(), 32, 32, new Paint(Color.YELLOW));
            //canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.icon_photo), 100, 100, null);
            Log.i("FLOAT", "Drawing f=" + f.getX() + "/" + f.getY());
        }
    }
}

class Floater {
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    private Bitmap mImage;
    private Context mContext;

    public Floater(Bitmap img, Context c){
        mImage = img;
        this.x = getRandomX();
        this.y = getRandomY();
        mContext = c;
    }

    public Floater(Bitmap img, int x, int y, Context c){
        mImage = img;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getX() { return x; }
    public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
    public int getY() { return y; }
    public void setY(int y) { this.y = y; }
    public Bitmap getImage(){ return mImage; }

    private int getRandomX(){
        return new Random().nextInt(400);
    }

    private int getRandomY(){
        return new Random().nextInt(800);
    }
}
```

And my Screensaver thread

```
public class ScreensaverThread extends Thread {
    private GaggleSurfaceView mSurface = null;
    private boolean mRunning = false;

    public ScreensaverThread(GaggleSurfaceView sv){
            mSurface = sv;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run){
        mRunning = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(mRunning){
            Canvas canvas = mSurface.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            if(canvas != null){
                synchronized(mSurface.getHolder()){
                    mSurface.drawFloaters(canvas);
                }
                mSurface.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
            try{
                sleep(30);
            }catch(InterruptedException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main activity XML

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <view
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.goosesys.gaggle.screensaver.GaggleSurfaceView"
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:background="@color/Black" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtForShort"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtFriendlyName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtFriendlyName"
        android:text="@string/orinoco_for_short"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgBubble"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="128dp"
        android:maxWidth="128dp"
        android:src="@drawable/orinoco_bubble" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDesignatedId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtOrinocoHeader"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/orinoco_id_placeholder"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/Orange" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtOr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDesignatedId"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/orinoco_or"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFriendlyName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtOr"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/orinoco_friendly_name_placeholder"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/Orange" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAssignedTo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtForShort"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/orinoco_assigned_header"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAssignedDriver"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtAssignedTo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/orinoco_assigned_driver_placeholder"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/Orange"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtOrinocoHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgBubble"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/orinoco_greeting"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_login"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTrainingMode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/orinoco_training_button"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtVersion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgBubble"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtAssignedTo"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to try when you can't see anything at all is to just fill the entire surface with a single obvious color (e.g. red).  That way, if any part of the surface is visible, you'll see it.

For a SurfaceView, the next thing to try is to move the surface from being behind everything, to being in front of everything, by calling `setZOrderOnTop(true)` from the point where the SurfaceView object is created.  That way if your drawing code is doing anything you'll see the surface on top of the UI.

The third thing to try is to get rid of `android:background="@color/Black"`, which is probably the source of your trouble.  SurfaceViews have two parts, the View and the Surface.  The Surface part is a separate layer that sits behind everything else; the View part is supposed to be a place-holder that the layout code uses to provide a transparent "window" to the surface behind, but you've made it opaque, so nothing can show through.