# background image is not showing in surfaceholder

Tags: android, android-activity

I tried to show background moving image and moving 2d line image and ball image but it doesn't show.

This is my code:

```
backGround = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
            R.drawable.ab);

    // decrement the far background
            mBGFarMoveX = mBGFarMoveX - 1;

            // decrement the near background
            mBGNearMoveX = mBGNearMoveX - 4;

            // calculate the wrap factor for matching image draw
            int newFarX = backGround.getWidth() - (-mBGFarMoveX);

            // if we have scrolled all the way, reset to start
            if (newFarX <= 0) {
                mBGFarMoveX = 0;
                // only need one draw
                c.drawBitmap(backGround, mBGFarMoveX, 0, null);

            } else {
                // need to draw original and wrap
                c.drawBitmap(backGround, mBGFarMoveX, 0, null);
                c.drawBitmap(backGround, newFarX, 0, null);
            }
```

Everything is going on well except showing the background image..
background showing like black color and my program runs very slowly.

Comment: check this link it will be helpful to you,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089784/setting-image-background-in-surfaceview-getting-black-screen

Comment: how to display background image in activity

Comment: how to check dashing of two objects